# Como retirar o e.preventDefault() de um formulário com parametro?

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde, meu formulário está apresentando aquele efeito tipico de recarregamento da página porque eu estou passando um parametro (id) pra ele..

```
<form onSubmit={(id) =>EditandoTask(tarefa.id)}>
          <input/>
          <button
            type={"submit"}
          >
            salvar
          </button>
</form>


const EditandoTask = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
   
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<form onSubmit={(id) =>EditandoTask(event, tarefa.id)}>
          <input/>
          <button
            type={"submit"}
          >
            salvar
          </button>
</form>


const EditandoTask = (event, tarefaId) => {

    event.preventDefault();
   
  }
```

vc precisa passar o parâmetro `event` e também o `tarefaId` pra que possa ser utilizado: `EditandoTask = (event, tarefaId)`